# Revolutions of wheels with different radius in a vehicle

Tags: geometry

The rear wheel of a motorbike is larger in diameter than its front wheel.  The measure of their radii are 21 cm and 28 cm.  The motorbike travelled 99 km in 1 hour and 15 minutes.  Assuming that the speed of the bike didn't change during the entire journey, the difference in the number of revolutionsnof the two wheels per minute is ?

I know that speed of both the wheels should be (99*100000)/75 cm/min ... I am not really able to understand now how the 99 km distance travelled by car can be found from the wheels radius and speed.  Please help me out

Comment: Hint: 99 km = N revolutions * $(2 \pi R)$. Do this for both wheels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the wheels travel $9900000\mathrm{cm}$ in $75\mathrm{min.}$, they travel $132000\mathrm{cm/min.}$

The smaller front wheel with a circumference of $2\pi r\approx 132\mathrm{cm}$ makes$$\frac{132000}{132}=1000\mathrm{rpm}$$The larger rear wheel with a circumference of $2\pi r\approx 176\mathrm{cm}$ makes$$\frac{132000}{176}=750\mathrm{rpm}$$The difference in revolutions per minute is thus$$1000-750=250\mathrm{rpm}$$